# Can I pass bundled data and then destroy the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

If I try to pass data from one activity to another, but before going to another activity, I destroy the initial activity, then I cannot pass data. Look at the code

```
            //set bundle to pass data from initial activity
            bundle = new Bundle();
            data1 = Double.valueOf(myEditText.getText().toString());
            bundle.putDouble("data1", data1);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

When I now try to get data in AnotherActivity via

```
myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

I get nothing.

Comment: Are you using the same keys to extract the data?

Comment: do you have use ?
String param1 = bundle.getString(“data1″);

Comment: Yes, the same keys. The whole bundle is null. If I remove `finish()`, then I can receive the bundle properly.

Comment: for that you can use `intent_of_lastpg.putExtra("score", int_score);
      startActivity(intent_of_lastpg);   finish();`

Comment: I cannot as the app goes forward. All previous pages are finished. How do you mean without bundle? Are you referring to sharedpreferences or something else. The bundle seems the fastest way.

Comment: Hm, I will test this as soon as I return home. I might have made a mistake and though it was up to the finish() method. Could someone tell me where the Bundle object is kept? Inside of application Context or Activity's context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is bundle in this case and instance variable? If so, that might be the problem. Try just creating a new bundle instance for this particular intent that you're going to send.

Comment: He means:
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Instead of:
bundle = new Bundle(); //where bundle is a field of the activity?

However, the Bundle is a Parcel which gets serialised into the Extras of the Intent and shouldn't be GCed when the original Bundle is...

Answer (score 2):

I have used this type of code several time.and it's run fine.
You need to  check out  data1 = Double.valueOf(myEditText.getText().toString());
Is date1 is null?
Need to check retrieve method in next Activity.
other then no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
String value = "any data u want in another activity";
b.putStringArray("value", value);
Intent i = new Intent(CutrrentActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

// in another activity

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String value = b.getString("value");
```

Comment: This is the same code as mine. Have you tried it? Once you call finish(), the bundle is killed as well.